# Microphone amp using flex/AS

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, mxml, mxmlc

Is there a amplifier kind of version written in action script or flex is so please lead me to relevant examples for it..

Amplifier meaning to change the control the frequency pitch etc....

can any one give me links to it??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you http://www.kelvinluck.com/2008/11/first-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/

I have seen some as3 libraries that do this as well, if you are interested I can post them

Regards,

Oliver

Comment: FYI, they'll smack you for adding signatures or links into your answer like that  ;)   http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: @Nate Sorry for that... I don't know what was in my mind with that.I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Rajeev: Here they are

Standingwave:
https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3
even better...
Sion
http://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/example

Hope it helps you!